# Memcache + PHP - Why data is not expiring?

Tags: php, memcached

I have a simple example where I set a value for 5 seconds. The problem is that after 5 seconds; I still get back a value when I expected 'false'.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");


$memcache->set('foo', 'bar', 0, 5); // 5 seconds expiry
var_dump($memcache->get('foo')); // bar
sleep(10);
var_dump($memcache->get('foo')); // still shows bar
```

Here is the memcache server version

Server's version: 1.4.13

Comment: I'm curious, since I tested in my machine and I am seeing bool(false) in the second case.

Comment: I am seeing 'bar' in both outputs

Comment: Try sleeping for 10 seconds, just to take out any possible overlap.

Comment: I cant reproduce too. works fine..

Comment: @MikePurcell sleeping 10 seconds shows same results :( :(

Comment: Was just to remove possible distractor. Have you tried using the `memcached` api?

Comment: @MikePurcell can u elaborate what you mean by "using the memcached api'?

Comment: There are two PHP extensions, `memcache` and `memcached`. The latter is a bit newer and talks the binary protocol, IIRC.

Comment: Take a look at the docs. I've only ever used `memcached` for all the projects I have worked on. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Comment: @shergill can you try doing `telnet 0 11211` and doing a `get foo`.  What do you get back as output? Memcache protocol is described here <http://code.sixapart.com/svn/memcached/trunk/server/doc/protocol.txt>.

Comment: root@server:~# php test.php (copy-pasted the above code)
string(3) "bar"
bool(false)

Comment: oops, http:// is missed! @shergill, did you try looking into the instance using telnet?

Comment: Can't reproduce, its doing exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: I'm wondering if your memcache.ini has a setting that's causing this behavior. Could you post the contests of your memcache.ini file?

Comment: @MichaelTaggart can you please advise where to find memcache.ini file?

Comment: @shergill It depends what OS you are using. If you are on Ubuntu with it will be at /etc/php5/conf.d/memcache.ini

Answer (score 5):

Late to the game, but in your code it looks like you are passing "0" for the expiration (not "5"), which translates to "never expire"  Specifically:

```
 $memcache->set('foo', 'bar', 0, 5); // 5 seconds expiry
```

Should be:

```
 $memcache->set('foo', 'bar', 5); // 5 seconds expiry
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding [the PHP documentation located here](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php), which shows that the set command takes three parameters:

```
 public bool Memcached::set ( string $key , mixed $value [, int $expiration ] )
```

Edit: Whoops, I see that you're using the Memcache extension and not Memcached, [which does have four parmaters](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php).  Perhaps try using the MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED constant instead of 0 to see if it works:

```
 $memcache->set('foo', 'bar', MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 5); // 5 seconds expiry
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in the memcached server including version 1.4.13 through at least 1.4.14 that, once the memcached server had been running for some time, it would sometimes get into a mode where it would fail to properly expire values.

Restarting the service fixed it for me, and I'm hopeful that the newer versions fix it more permanently.

Comment: Where can I find info about this?
Was it fixed in 1.5.x versions?

Comment: Confirmed this exists in `1.4.15` as well unfortunately

Comment: Confirmed this issue on `1.5.10`. Where can I find this documented?

Answer (score 1):

As the code looks fine - the next chain down the line is to look at either your version of the memcache PHP extension not working, or memcached server itself.

This get a but tricky. Easiest is to rule out memcached server first. (There's a php interface you can install - but that won't help you work outwhich bit.) So...

In terminal (or command window in Windows) type

```
 telnet localhost 11211
```

(Note - telnet client is not installed in Windows by default - go to "control panel", "turn windows features on or off" and add from there.)

This gives you access to memcached.

Then type

```
stats items
```

which lists the memory items in memcached.

Hopefully you've only got one slab, so note its number and type

```
stats cachedump [Number] 0
```

And this will list what's recorded in cache.

If this still shows "bar" (in encoded format) then it's memcached server that's not working - upgrade for a newer version.

If this doesn't show "bar" (or, preferably, the item just doesn't exist - you get ERROR instead) then it'll be the memcache extension to PHP that's not working. Again, check your version of that.

When done, type

```
quit
```

---

Alternative is to check out "memcached" (php extension) and rewrite your PHP code with those classes. It's newer. If that still fails, it's definately memcached server; if that works that it was the php memcache extension.

Comment: Here is what I get

stats items
STAT items:1:number 1
STAT items:1:age 15
STAT items:1:evicted 0
STAT items:1:evicted_nonzero 0
STAT items:1:evicted_time 0
STAT items:1:outofmemory 0
STAT items:1:tailrepairs 0
STAT items:1:reclaimed 0
STAT items:1:expired_unfetched 0
STAT items:1:evicted_unfetched 0

so does that mean that the memcache server is not working as the item is still in cache?

Comment: Try the last instruction above (stats cachedump 1 0) and it should give you something back.